How is Edwin Jaynes' Partition function in "Probability Theory: the Logic of Science" related to partition function in statistical physics?
In Section 9.6 of his book "Probability Theory: the Logic of Science", Edwin Jaynes proposed "partition function" when trying to compute the "multiplicity factors" $M(n,G)$ in the following setting.
Suppose we have a system consisting of $n$ particles and $m$ states, state $j$ has energy $g_j$. Let total energy be $G$, and the number of possible configurations for $n$ particles corresponding to a fixed total energy $G$ be $M(n,G)$.
By recursive relation $M(n,G)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^m M(n-1,G-g_j)$, Jaynes got following expression:
$$\sum_G \exp(-\lambda G)M(n,G)=Z^n(\lambda),$$
where $\lambda$ is a constant, $Z(\lambda) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^m \exp(-\lambda g_j)$ is called "partition function" by Jaynes.
I wonder, if anyone has idea how this "partition function" here is related to the partition function in statistical physics?  From what I learned, there are at least 2 differences:

partition function in statistical physics is $Z=\sum\limits_i\exp(-\beta E_i)$, which is summation over all possible system energies, not individual particle energies.
in statistical physics, partition is closely related to system probability at specific energy $P(E)=\exp(-\beta E) / Z$, while here it is not clear to me how probability is related to the partition function.

Just curious if anyone has any insights regarding this?  Any idea would be much appreciated.

I would call this one-particle partition function, but in the context of the (given chapter of) Jaynes' book it seems to cause no ambiguity.
Let us look at the usual state.mech. Suppose we have $n$ non-interacting particles, each of which can be in  in $m$ states with energies $E_i$. As usual, $\beta = 1/(k_B T)$. I assume canonical ensemble. Then the energy of a given configuration is
$$
E(i_1,...,i_n)=E_{i_1}+...+E_{i_n}=\sum_{k=1}^nE_{i_k}.
$$
The partition function is a sum over all the possible configurations of particles:
$$
Z(\beta)=\sum_{i_1=1}^m...\sum_{i_n=1}^me^{-\beta E(i_1,...,i_n)}=
\sum_{i_1=1}^me^{- \beta E_{i_1}}\times ... \times \sum_{i_n=1}^me^{- \beta E_{i_n}}=
\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\sum_{i_k=1}^me^{- \beta E_{i_k}}\right)=
\left[Z_1(\beta)\right]^n,
$$
where
$$
Z_1(\beta)=\sum_{i=1}^me^{- \beta E_{i}}.
$$

Thanks for the reply!  Is there any connection between this partition function with the probability here?  In Jaynes' derivation, the probability of system with energy G is proportional to number of possible configurations M(n,G) (assuming all configurations have equal probability), how do we connect this M(n,G) with partition function $Z_1(\beta)$?

@username123 $Z_1$ is related to the probabilities for one particle, while $Z=[Z_1]^n$ is for the probabilities for the system of $n$ (non-interacting) particles - just as in Jaynes' book. See, e.g., his equation (9.27). The notation is somewhat unusual, but  the content is not very different.
